# (React) TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

I'm new to web development and it'd be nice to receive more info regarding an error I'm receiving.

I fetched information from a time API and passed them to the relevant component. I need to manipulate the data and extract some info from a string.

Unfortunately, I am unable to understand what I'm doing wrong and fix the issue by myself.

```
function App() {
const [time, setTime] = useState([]);

const getTime = () =>
    fetch("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setTime(data));

useEffect(getTime, []);

return (
<Clock time={time} />
 )
}



export default function Clock({ time }) {
const extractTime = time.datetime.substr(12, 4);

return (
<div className="time-container">
            <p className="time">{extractTime}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any clarification is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you first render `Clock` `time` is still an empty array because the data is still being fetched - it's an asynchronous process, which is why you're getting the error - there is no data *yet*. You need to add something like `if (!time.length) return <div />` before you try to return `Clock` so you can catch that issue. Note: instead of `<div />` a lot of people use a "spinner" component here to indicate that something *is* happening.

```
function App() {

  const [time, setTime] = useState([]);

  const getTime = () =>
    fetch("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setTime(data));

  if (!time.length) return <div />;

  return <Clock time = {time} />;

}
```